# how to stop repainting of a widget when it's resized

Tags: qt, qt4, kde-plasma

i am making a software in which paint event painting a widget as per my need but the problem

is that when i re-size my application window it  painted it again  so please tell me the way

to stop paint event from painting my widget on resizing the main window.

my file are:

v_lab.h(http://qt.pastebin.com/tjHAWkPH)
v_lab.cpp(http://qt.pastebin.com/teJDmMmt)
main.cpp(http://qt.pastebin.com/gsUytaCN)

Thanks

Comment: This looks like the same program that was asked about in these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742520/problem-with-random-number-generation-and-displaying-with-qpainter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742796/problem-in-tab-background. Do you want to prevent the repaint so that your random numbers aren't regenerated? Your name appears in the source from the other questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do want to redraw every time the main window resizes. But your design is somewhat weird, as you are creating random stuff inside the `paintEvent` function. You should create that stuff elsewhere as needed, store that stuff in a QPixmap or something and just redraw the image in the `paintEvent` function.

In other words, `paintEvent` should only repaint the view in its current state and should not contain anything that changes the state.